# Show that $(I-A^n)$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be  symmetric and nilpotent matrix for some $m\in\mathbb N$. Show that there is some $\exists m_0\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $\forall m>m_0$, the matrix $\left(I-A^m\right)$ is invertible, $I_n$ being the identity matrix.

My trouble is with the $A^m$ since $(I-A)$ can be shown easily.

Comment: Do you really mean $(I - A^n)$? Then take $n_0$ as the nilpotency degree of $A$. For all $n > n_0$, we then have $(I - A^n) = I$ and this is invertible.

Comment: The only real symmetric and niplotent matrix is $A = 0$.  Could you have copied something incorrectly?

Comment: If $A$ is *any* nilpotent matrix, then $I - A^n$ will be invertible for all $n \geq 1$.  This question is very bizarre

Answer (score 1):

You have $$(I_n-A^m)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}A^{nm}$$ (notice this is a finite sum because $A$ is nilpotent) because
$$ (I_n-A^m)\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}A^{nm}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(A^{nm}-A^{(n+1)m}\right) =I_n$$
because $A$ is nilpotent and thus $A^k=0$ for $k$ large enough. The hypothesis $A$ symetric is useless here.